# To qualify of or to qualify as degenerate

Tags: prepositions

Which of those is correct?

> (1) We qualify those of degenerate.
>
> (2) We qualify those as degenerate.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

First, to answer directly: #2 is correct.

The choice of preposition there depends on the verb, I think. Sentences meaning something similar could include:

- We label those as degenerate
- We think of those as degenerate
- We consider those degenerate

I'm sure there are more options that use other prepositions while still meaning essentially the same thing.